# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices'

Tags: python, azure

I will say up front I'm new to python and I'm moving from using a Notebook in Azure (within a lab) toward trying to get this to work on my home system.  I'm getting this error when running the following line of code:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient <-------------


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices'
  
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']

>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages'
>>>

C:\Python>python -m pip freeze
azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision==0.7.0
azure-common==1.1.26
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
idna==2.10
isodate==0.6.0
msrest==0.6.20
oauthlib==3.1.0
Pillow==8.1.0
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.26.3
```

I have searched for a solution to this but the solutions I have found don't seem to apply.   If someone could explain a solution that is more descriptive I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is `Python39` ? Can you tell us how to reproduce it ?

Answer (score 1):

Run the line below, then it will work fine.

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision
```